# Accsss SQL query using a "where" clause to link on memo field (long text) but Access is droping records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to join a table and a query on a long text field in MS Access. As Access prevents such a join, I am using a Where clause as a workaround. The issue is that I am losing 80ish less records in the query's result as expected although the query is otherwise producing the results I want/need. I am simply unable to see what the issue is. Thank you so much for your help.

**Query 1**: q_Responses_Question1Through7_IntermediateStep3, (#Records=784) Structure:

- Field 1: Name=ID, Primary Key, Type=AutoNumber
- Field 2: Name=Question7, Type=Long Text, No null values

**Table 1**: t_LookUp_Question7_Responses (#Records=657) Structure:

- Field 1: Name=Q7_ID, Primary Key, Type=AutoNumber
- Field 2: Name=Description, Type=Long Text

**MS Access SQL Query** (#Results 695):

SELECT A.ID, B.Q7_ID

FROM q_Responses_Question1Through7_IntermediateStep3 AS A, t_LookUp_Question7_Responses AS B

WHERE (A.Question7=B.Description);

Comment: . . I am guessing that the 80 results that are "missing" are really strings that you might think are the same but are not.

Comment: That indeed is the case. Thank you. I figured it was a stupid issue but I couldnt think through it. Again, thank you.